# Create lucene indexWriter overhead?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

`IndexWriter myWriter = new IndexWriter(pathOnDisk);
int segCount = myWriter.GetSegmentCount();
if (segCount > 1)
   myWriter.Optimize();
myWriter.Close()`

I want to run the above code for 50 different index directory, so i want to know if opening an indexwriter has overhead ?

Answer (score 0):

It has some overhead, including creating a lock file (see line 133), reading the segment infos, and a bunch of other stuff that may or may not be expensive.

> 0113 Opening an IndexWriter creates a lock file for the directory in use. Trying to open
>   another IndexWriter on the same directory will lead to a
>   {@link LockObtainFailedException}. The {@link LockObtainFailedException}
>     is also thrown if an IndexReader on the same directory is used to delete documents
>   from the index.

Check out the [java source](http://www.search-lucene.com/c?id=Lucene:/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.java%7C%7CIndexWriter.java), starting at line 816.  It's not a small constructor, but you'll have to be the judge of how significant it is.